# Остановка времени в time.process_time

Tags: python, python-3.8

В этот раз на голову мне упала идея использовать не `clock` в связке с отключением предупреждений `DeprecationWarning`, а `process_time`. Сейчас вижу одну и ту же картину: `process_time` всегда возвращает `0.078125`. То есть минута, вторая, а он и не желает мне вернуть что-то другое. Скрипт, несколько запусков, несколько других терминалов... Картина одна на всех. Баг может и еденичный, но я програмку протестить не успел, как она уже не работает. Хотелось бы больше стабильности-. В частности вопрос к любителям 3.8 версии. **Чем вы заменили `time.clock`?**

Comment: Какая ОС? У меня `process_time` работает нормально

Comment: Windows 10 Pro (версия 1909), но имеется и linux, у которого какие то терки с виндой по поводу времени. Не шарю.

Comment: Точность таймера на WIndows — ±16 миллисекунд. Если накинуть нагрузки побольше и подождать подольше, то значение изменится

Comment: @andreymal, в ответ можете вынести? В цикле while он действительно обновляет свое значение, а после стоит на одном и том же.